# iOS background download not respecting httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am on iOS 14.2...
I have a URLSession that i configure that way:

```
private lazy var backgroundURLSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "background-download")
    
    config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
    config.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
    
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()
```

I give it like 100 URLs to download

```
    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: offlineTile.url)
    downloadTask.resume()
```

and even with `httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2` the server gets ALL requests at ONCE... ?!?
What could I be doing wrong

One more note: We have a Varnish Cache in the background... and noticed that the behavior differs, if Varnish is set to pipe (no caching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case it was the load balancer of our server that did not properly to it's https termination, which caused iOS to send all requests at basically once.